# Show global messages of newsletter subscription in popup

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter, popup, global-messages

I wish to show newsletter subscription global messages(like Thank you for your subscription.etc.) in popup.When a user click on newsletter subscription the default global message should come in popup.
Followed this approach both at app/design/frontend/theme/template/page/1column.phtml and app/design/frontend/theme/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml

> ```
> <script type=“text/javascript”>
> var message = '<?php echo strip_tags($this->getChildHtml('global_messages')) ?>';
> if (message == $this->__('Thank you for your subscription')) alert("What  ever you want to display!");
> ```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: It will not work like this. You need to create your own fancy-box or popup and notification. And you placed $this in if condition in JS code , that will also not work

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: use sweet alert to display your message in popup http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, but I am unable to get global massges in alert, tried with session variable also

Comment: try like this: alert('<?php $yourmessage; ?>'); and remove $this from your if condition

Comment: When i use for it without any condition for any global messge then also i will not work for me 
var message = '<?php echo strip_tags($this->getChildHtml('global_messages')) ?>';
if (message) alert("What  ever you want to display!");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51875/discussion-between-bhagyashree-and-borncoder).